# Correlation problem when analysing the effectiveness of a vaccine

Tags: correlation, causality

I was having a heated debate with a friend on this question, we now know that the covi-shield has 63% effectiveness which is a reasonable amount of trust. Now, this 63% was concluded by running on mass test on a population , and now suppose we take one individual in that population mass.

And now let's say we don't have to mechanism to determine whether his success in overcoming the disease was due to the vaccine or not.

This leads to a problem, since we can't judge for an individual but only relatively, eventually what may happen is that many people who have survived covid , the reason would not even be the vaccine (maybe genetics), hence they would be in a way giving a false contribution to the percent. Getting more people vaccinated would also lead increasing the sample of people who survived covid but not actually due to the vaccine.

Hence, my question: would there be a way to account (and correct) for this phenomena of 'success due to wrong causes' happening statistically?

Comment: "The success due to wrong causes" is eliminated by conducting a larger number of tests.

Comment: I don't think so, maybe all the people who you test for shave something else in common which causes their success and hence even taking a larger pool, you can't really figure out if it was indeed the vaccine or not which caused the success.

Comment: Is also eliminating by having **controls** who have not received the vaccine, combined with **random assignment to vaccine or control**: the effectiveness compares rates of infection in vaccinated versus (unvaccinated) controls. If we see a difference between the vaccinated and the controls, and if treatment/control was randomized, then with a large enough sample any effect should be due to treatment. Random assignment reduces the effect of the "specialness" of study participants on differences in infection rates to chance—with a lower chance of such effect in high sample sizes.